# activar funcion JS cuando trae valor establecido

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un pagina para actualizar donde me trae los datos segun el registro que haya seleccionado, tengo campos numericos
que los he validado con una funcion de separacion de miles y decimales, pero en que metodo debo colocar la funcion para que 
al cargar los valores numeros automaticamente me formateé el valor sin necesidad de hacer un focusin, focusOut, keypress o keyup

```js
function formatearNumero(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split(',');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtValor">
```

Comment: La pregunta es, ¿En qué momento quieres que se aplique dicha función? Recuerda que detrás de una función siempre debe haber un evento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea seria después de tu **ajax** recorrer cada registro e invocar cada una de las cantidades y pasarlas a la función `formatearNumero()` así:

**Este es un ejemplo para que te guies**

```js
const cifras = [100,1000,2050.60];

function formatearNumero(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split(',');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

cifras.forEach(function(cifra) {
  console.log(formatearNumero(cifra));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora si ya las cantidades las tienes en los **inputs** puedes hacer esto:

```js
function formatearNumero(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split(',');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

alert("Los campos aun no estan formateados, una vez que le des aceptar en el alert se formatearan")

$(".cifra").each(function(){
  var valorFormateado = formatearNumero($(this).val());
  $(this).val(valorFormateado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="cifra" value="100">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="cifra" value="1000">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="cifra" value="2050.60">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```